# Php blazing fast on Windows, awfully slow on Centos7

Tags: php, linux, centos7

Ok, so. As I stated in the title, I've got a PHP app that is so slow on Centos7, it eventually returns Time Out error after running for 60 seconds.

Load time on Windows is around 6-7 seconds, which is quite acceptable considering the app makes 5 cURL calls per run.

I've been trying to fix it for over a week, still no luck.

- I've tried tuning Apache, it helped a bit, but still every 2 runs out of 5, result in timeout, other 3 makes me age while waiting.
- Tried running PHP as FPM served by Nginx, FastCGI served by Apache, FPM served by Apache.
- It's a dedicated server, not an oversold VPS or something.
- I thought it could be my code, but even running this simple function below takes 10 seconds on server, but 0.5 sec on my Windows laptop.

  ```
  $tags = get_meta_tags("http://stackoverflow.com");
  print_r($tags);
  ```
- I narrowed down the problem quite a bit, bottlenecks on my code are these cURL/file_get_html calls. Each take around 7-10 seconds. API endpoints are AWS and Google services, so they respond instantly.

My server:

- Centos7
- PHP: 7.0.27 (Installed via Plesk). Tried running higher PHP versions as well.
- CPU: 64 Bit
- 32 GB Ram
- Virtualized with openvz

My dev env:

- 64-Bit Windows laptop
- PHP installed via Xampp, version 7.1

Could you please guide me in the right direction? If I could only fasten up these cURL requests a bit, I'll be ready to deliver the app...

Huge thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like DNS / network related problem if it's happening when you perform requests. Is it PHP, or the server? Use ping or trace route in the terminal and see if it looks normal. After that I'd start looking at server logs. CentOS 7 itself should be fine. If it wasn't there'd surely be a lot of people complaining about it.

Comment: To me looks more a server problem than PHP each self like Brian says.
You should first establish that your server network is running  perfect.